# how to wake up app from beacon in specific range?

Tags: swift, beacon

Is that possible to set wake up distance? If it is possible, how to set wake up distance / minimum rssi ?

I want to set wake up application within minimum distance is 5 meters or set up to minimum rssi value. Now I only can wake up application from beacon based on its default range to wake up.

I'm using Swift 3 to develop app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS CoreLocation APIs provide no ability to set a minimum distance for callbacks from beacon monitoring.  The common approach to accomplish something similar is to use Beacon ranging.

You accomplish this by starting both monitoring and ranging at the same time:

```
locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: region)
locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
```

The monitoring callback will wake up your app in the background when a beacon is first detected, and ranging will start automatically.  Then in the ranging callback you perform your logic only when the minimum distance condition is met:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  for beacon in beacons {
    // Is beacon less than 5 meters away?
    if beacon.accuracy < 5.0 {
      // Custom logic here
    }
}
```

There are a few caveats to this:

1. In the background, you only get 10 seconds of ranging after a beacon is first detected in the region.  So if you detect a beacon in the background at the outer edge of its transmission range (say 40 meters), you will only trigger the custom logic if the user gets within 5 meters within 10 seconds.  There are ways to [lengthen the time of background ranging to 180 seconds](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html) to make this more practical.
2. The ranging callback fires every second.  So if you want to execute your logic only once, you must set some kind of flag to keep it from executing over and over every second.

Comment: is  beacon.accuracy in meter? because, when I start monitoring, real distance is less than 1 meter, but in logs, it says that beacon.accuracy more than 1 meter (maybe 3.xxxxxxx). How to make the difference from real distance and beacon.accuracy is not too far?

Comment: While accuracy is expressed in meters, understand that beacon distance estimates are based on fluctuating radio signal strength measurements and are therefore inexact.  You can calibrate your beacons "measured power" setting for the best possible results, but they will still be inexact.